# How do I read and write files to the server with Meteor?

Tags: javascript, file, meteor

I'm working on a NoDB CMS in Meteor, but I'm new to both Meteor and JavaScript frameworks.

How do I go about reading and writing files to the server?

Comment: More specifically I would like to read an image file from the server, manipulate it, and then save a separate version back to the server in another directory.

Comment: When I attempt to load the node FS like this: var fs = Npm.require('fs'); I get an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Npm is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try to use Npm.require inside the startup function. Like so

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
   fs = Npm.require('fs');
}
```

But you should definitely have a look at [collectionFS](https://github.com/raix/Meteor-CollectionFS) that does what you are looking for: storing files on the server and allowing you to retrieve them

an added advantage is that you can distribute everything over many nodes of a MongoDB cluster

to manipulate image files, you can use [imagemagick with nodejs](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick) this should allow you to transform in any way you need.

Comment: I still get the not defined error, even using that startup function. Should I be defining Npm somewhere, somehow?

Comment: please run  meteor --version if you have a version prior to 0.6 the Npm is not defined

Comment: I have the latest version of Meteor.

Comment: that's weird one. What's your OS?

Comment: can you post the filename, the location of the file and the code where it fails? the only explanation I can find, is that you are trying to use Npm in client code.

Comment: That was it - trying to run it in the client instead of the server! Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Within the Node fs module you have a [writeFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback) function.

```
getUser = Meteor.users.findOne({_id : Meteor.userId()});
userObject = JSON.stringify(getUser);
var path = process.env["PWD"] + "/public/";
fs.writeFile(process.env["PWD"] + "/public/"+Meteor.userId()+'.txt', userObject, 
        function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
              console.log('Done!');
        }
    );
```

The above snippet would create a file with all the information of the user. You could access the properties of the result of your query with something like `getUser._id` to prepare your *data* parameter (String or Buffer) to print pretty.

All this of course is server side.

Answer (score 0):

The node fs module is a start. http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

You might want to be a bit more specific with your question though, as it's kind of broad.

Comment: That looks like it should work just fine. How do I get it setup within a Meteor project?

Comment: I've tried nothing yet, not being familiar with Meteor, I don't know where to start. If I require(fs) do it put that in the server folder? If I do, how do I call it from the client?

Comment: OK, so if you're not familiar with Meteor: familiarize yourself with Meteor first. This is too advanced for your first Meteor app.

Comment: So now I'm somewhat more familiar. I did this: if (Meteor.isClient) {
 Meteor.startup(function () {
  fs = npm.require('fs');
 });
} and put that in my main.js file. But I get a 'npm not defined' error.

Comment: You can't use npm on the client, only the server.